# One JSON file with multiple getJSON requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I currently have the following javascript file:

```
$(function () {
  'use strict';
  getAlbums();
});

function getAlbums() {
  'use strict';
  var name = '',
    photos = '',
    id = '',
    displayAlbum = '',
    albumThumb = '',
    albumImage = '',
    albumCaption = '';
  $.getJSON('/assets/js/images.json', function (data) {
    var album = data.albums;
    $.each(album, function (i, item) {
      name = item.name;
      id = item.id;
      photos  = item.photos;

      displayAlbums(name, id, photos);
    });
  });
}

function displayAlbums(name, id, photos) {
  var displayAlbum = $('.templates .albums .thumb').clone(true),
      thumbnail    = displayAlbum.find('.thumbnail'),
      image        = displayAlbum.find('.thumbnail .image'),
      caption      = displayAlbum.find('.thumbnail .caption h4');

  caption.html(name);
  thumbnail.attr('id', id);
  image.attr('src', photos[0].href);
  image.attr('alt', photos[0].href);

  $('.img-container .row').append(displayAlbum);
}

function displayGallery(request) {
  'use strict';
  var test = $(request).attr('id'),
      gallery = '',
      displayImages = '';

  $('.img-container').hide();
}
```

The JSON files has a list of albums, each with a name, ID, and an array of image links to my assets folder. What I currently am doing is I'm loading the first image on each album as a thumbnail that will link to the gallery of remaining images. So if I click on one album thumbnail, that specific gallery will load.

What I'm having trouble with is the album thumbnails load with the page. What I need to do next is make it so that when I click on one of the albums, it will make a call to load that specific gallery.

So my question is, do I need to make a separate 'getJSON' function to load the gallery? Or can I use the same 'getAlbums' function I've already defined?

Here is a sample of my json file as well:

```
{
  "albums": [
    {
      "name": "Ancillary & Specialty Rooms",
      "id": 1,
      "photos": [
        {
          "href": "/assets/images/specialty rooms/1.jpg",
          "title": "image 1"
        },
        {
          "href": "/assets/images/specialty rooms/2.jpg",
          "title": "image 2"
        },
        {
          "href": "/assets/images/specialty rooms/3.jpg",
          "title": "image 3"
        },
        {
          "href": "/assets/images/specialty rooms/4.jpg",
          "title": "image 4"
        },
        {
          "href": "/assets/images/specialty rooms/5.jpg",
          "title": "image 5"
        },
        {
          "href": "/assets/images/specialty rooms/6.jpg",
          "title": "image 6"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Bathrooms",
      "id": 2,
      "photos": [
        {
          "href": "/assets/images/bathrooms/1.jpg",
          "title": "image 1"
        },
        {
          "href": "/assets/images/bathrooms/2.jpg",
          "title": "image 2"
        },
        {
          "href": "/assets/images/bathrooms/3.jpg",
          "title": "image 3"
        },
        {
          "href": "/assets/images/bathrooms/4.jpg",
          "title": "image 4"
        },
        {
          "href": "/assets/images/bathrooms/5.jpg",
          "title": "image 5"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I appreciate any help I can get,

Thanks

UPDATE:

To specify more about what I want it to do. When a user clicks on the album for the gallery they want to view, the current div containing the album links will be hidden (or cleared, no sure yet) and the gallery will load on the same page.

Comment: You already received all of the data you need with the first request, there's no reason to send another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(displayAlbum).click(function() {displayGallery(this)})
```

What I'm thinking is that in your displayAlbums function just after you create displayAlbum by cloning from an existing element you can attach an onClick handler. When this is called - by the user clicking in the thumbnail it will call displayGallery. 'this' passed to displayGallery will be the clicked thumbnail - so you can examine this to get which thumbnail was clicked maybe off the id attribute you have.

I don't know what you want to do in displayGallery? Open in a new div?

This should work - or something like it.

Update:

I tried to figure out how you could do

```
$(displayAlbum).click(function() {displayGallery(this, photos)})
```

where photos is the JSON you have from your getJSON request which you've passed to displayAlbums()

Basically you should be able to pass the gallery part of the JSON to the click handler. So that when the thumbnail is clicked you can access that JSON. I ran into a problem with scope and eventually got a proof of concert to work on: JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/justinwyllie/cj3h17hd/
Of course since you are not using a loop; you may not have this problem. You may be able to pass photos directly to your click handler without a problem.

Also - I'd add I'm not sure why you are creating a new element (the thumbnail) by cloning from something already on the page. As I'm sure you know you can just create new elements on the fly with jQuery e.g. `$('#el').append('<span />')`. I don't know the pros and cons of your cloning approach.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out the best approach to how I want the data displayed. Right now, I'm leaning towards hiding the albums on the click and then showing the images in the selected gallery. I'm fairly new to javascript and jquery so I'm not too sure what you mean by your last paragraph. If you'd like, here's a link to the github page: https://github.com/Su7ech/sandsbuilders and the gh-pages for the project: http://tbaroody-dev.com/gallery.html

Comment: Hi Su7. This is your new gallery.js. https://gist.github.com/justinwyllie/0456803d637f7f2f503083dd2e738633 It does work but obviously needs a lot of work. Obviously you need to close the gallery and get them back to the thumbs now. My last paragraph: your approach to get new elements onto the page is to have one and then clone it. You don't need to do it this way. You can do: $('body').append($('<div />').attr('id', 'whatever').addClass('someclass').click(function() {}))

Comment: @Su7ech - btw the code in my displayGallery2() is an example of what I mean about creating new elements on the fly rather than basing them on existing page elements and a clone.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Makes so much more sense than what I was thinking of. Also your explanation of creating the elements on the fly makes perfect sense to me now and will really help with keeping my code clean. So again, THANK YOU! :)